# Karate sequential execution of feature groups and the consolidation of results into a single report

Tags: ui-automation, karate

I have two groups of feature files which are to run in sequence. Each group can run its feature files in parallel. Tried the following

```
Results results_1 = Runner.path("classpath:group1").tags("~@ignore").parallel(2);
assertEquals(0, results_1.getFailCount(), results_1.getErrorMessages());

Results results_2 = Runner.path("classpath:group2").tags("~@ignore").parallel(2);
assertEquals(0, results_2.getFailCount(), results_2.getErrorMessages());
```

Am I correct in assuming this always runs in the above order ?

And how do I consolidate it into a single report ?

Comment: I have done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will run in that order. You may need to combine the JSON report files manually into a single report: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo#example-report

Also it may be possible for you to combine the two `Results` objects into one. maybe you can contribute code for that.

But we really recommend fixing your tests to be able to run in parallel. Else you will forever be hacking your suite. Note that there is a `@parallel=false` tag that may help: https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallelfalse