# Need to show only pass and fail status in karate report

Tags: report, karate

For e.g if there is a feature file and if all of the steps are executed successfully then in the report I want to show the status as Pass. I don't want to show the status of each step in the report.
Is there any way to achieve the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't. You can ignore the report and use the `Results` class as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63351980/143475

EDIT: also refer this on how to write custom reports by hand: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66773839/143475