# Karate - Is there a way to display custom logo in the karate test report?

Tags: karate

Is there a way to load custom logo in Karate test report. I am using latest Karate version v0.9.6 and parallel test.

Comment: No. Write your own report if needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63356060/143475