# How can we customize Karate Report

Tags: testing, junit, cucumber, report, karate

Is There Any Way to Customize Karate Report. When I say Customized Karate Report, Which means I can write Log and add screenshot in report as we can do in cucumber report with help of scenario.log and Web driver.
[image: Customized Cucumber HTML Report]

Comment: please assume the answer is NO. but if you are willing to write some code, it MAY be possible, so see the linked answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63356060/143475

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Two more question can we add customize bar chart or pie chart in report. And second one, Is there  any possibility to combine multiple report in one report for analysis. Like yesterday report have passes some test cases. Today again I modified the project and rerun and it has generated some more passes test cases. Now I want to combine both report and wanted to see yesterday and todays report in same html report.

Comment: I have nothing to add to my answer above.